# decimal delimiter in mysql for cakephp app

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a CakePHP 1.3 website with a MySQL database. The problem is that i have some prices, double values, that are stored using a dot as a decimal delimiter, however my application front-end should display them using commas.

Is there a way to set this in the DB directly, or simply a better way to achieve this than str_replace EVERYWHERE? that would be such a hassle, and it just seems like bad practice to me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal in the database is correct- it's a decimal being used as a decimal.  To *display* it, you should use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could technically just do n str_replace in the model's afterFind handler and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$decimalNumberFromDb= 1234.56;
//
// French notation
//
$frenchNotation = number_format($decimalNumberFromDb, 2, ',', ' '); // Output: 1 234,56
//
// English Notation
//
$englishNotation = number_format($decimalNumberFromDb, 2, '.', ''); // Output: 1234.56
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot in your database is not a delimiter but the way decimals are stored.

You could do a select query like this

```
select *, REPLACE(CAST(price AS CHAR), '.', ',') as price_formatted from products;
```

Or with display it with PHP in other formats with number_format

```
$price = 1300222.99;
echo "Original:     ".$price.PHP_EOL;
echo "english/us:   ".number_format($price,2).PHP_EOL;
echo "Dutch/german: ".number_format($price, 2, ',', '.').PHP_EOL;
echo "French:       ".number_format($price, 2, ',', ' ').PHP_EOL;
echo "Swiss:        ".number_format($price, 2, ',', '\'').PHP_EOL;
```

example at http://codepad.org/WXjc7d2D

Comment: as mentioned, I am using cakephp, so there are no explicit sql queries like that.

Comment: @glasspill See `virtualFields` var $virtualFields = array('price_formatted' => "REPLACE(CAST(price AS CHAR), '.', ',')");

Comment: interesting, i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

you can use behaviors which do that for you:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Model/Behavior/DecimalInputBehavior.php